# MATLAB - Dependent properties and calculation

Tags: oop, matlab

Suppose I have the following class which calculates the solution to the quadratic equation:

```
classdef MyClass < handle
    properties
        a
        b
        c
    end
    properties (Dependent = true)
        x
    end

    methods
        function x = get.x(obj)
            discriminant = sqrt(obj.b^2 - 4*obj.a*obj.c);
            x(1) = (-obj.b + discriminant)/(2*obj.a);
            x(2) = (-obj.b - discriminant)/(2*obj.a);
        end
    end
end
```

Now suppose I run the following commands:

```
>>quadcalc = MyClass;
>>quadcalc.a = 1;
>>quadcalc.b = 4;
>>quadcalc.c = 4;
```

At this point, `quadcalc.x = [-2 -2]`. Suppose I call `quadcalc.x` multiple times without adjusting the other properties, i.e., `quadcalc.x = [-2 -2]` every single time I ask for this property. Is `quadcalc.x` *recalculated* every single time, or will it just "remember" [-2 -2]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `x` is recalculated every single time. This is kind of the point of having a dependent property, since it guarantees that the result in `x` is always up to date.

If you want to make `x` a "lazy dependent property", you may want to look at the suggestions in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961331/matlab-lazy-evaluation-in-dependent-property/4961387#4961387).

Comment: Suppose I used `x` in other dependent properties; `x` would also be recalculated for every other dependent property, yes?