# How to update all the variables when one variable is changed in a class in MATLAB?

Tags: oop, matlab

I am writing a Multiplier class that multiplies its two parameters. If parameters are not given, default value of 1 is given.
Now when I update one variable, I do not get the exact product. My code is as below:

```
    classdef Multiplier
    properties (SetAccess = public, GetAccess = public)
        first;
        second;

    end

    properties(SetAccess = immutable, GetAccess = public)
        product;

    end



    methods

        function obj = Multiplier(varargin)

            if nargin == 0
                obj.first = 1;
                obj.second = 1;



            end
            if nargin == 1
                obj.first = varargin{1};
                obj.second = 1;

            end
            if nargin > 1
                obj.first = varargin{1};
                obj.second = varargin{2};

            end

            obj.product = obj.first * obj.second;

         end
    end

    end


k = Multiplier
k.first = 5
k.product  -> This should return 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your `product` property `Dependent`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098935/matlab-dependent-properties-and-calculation) for an example.