# Extend vector class in matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, date, vector

I have stock price data with associated dates, stored in column vectors with matlab-formatted datenums.

I often need to do loops or lookups over dates, which as of now i realize using 'external bookkeeping', such as

```
for i = 1:length(dates)
    thisDate = dates(i)
end
```

or, even worse

```
iDate = find(dates == thisDate, 1)
```

I usually have to do very similar operations, so I would like to build a dates-object that encapsulates this functionality for me. It is trivial to do this by using public properties, such as

```
dates.datenum(i)
dates.datestr(i)
dates.findOneYearEarlier(i)
```

etc.

BUT

I need to be able to access the vector directly to maintain compatibility.

Thus, a direct access to my dates-object needs to result in a valid datenum.
Example:

```
dates(i) == 730910              % right now
dates.datenum(i) == 730910      % how I'm able to do it
```

I need both to work at the same time. Is there any way to accomplish this in matlab?

---

I came up with a few ideas, but I'm not sure how fruitful they are:

- instead of having an object that manages all dates, have just one date per object and then make a vector of those objects. Probably painfully slow, and difficult to build lookups...
- just extract a vector of datenums wherever required, and feed it into the old code. As the old stuff continually get updates, this complicates things, instead of making it easier.
- Extend the vector-class somehow, but I have absolutely no idea where to start with that.

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 2):

You can directly subclass `double`:

```
classdef myDateContainer < double

    methods
        % Constructor
        function this = myDataContainer(in)
            if nargin<1 || isempty(in)
                % default: zero
                in = 0;
            end
            this = this@double(in);
        end

        % add datestring functionality
        function str = datestring(this)
            dbl = double(this); %# cast to double to get at the value
            str = datestr(dbl); %# convert
        end
    end
end
```

To use:

```
date = myDateContainer(1:100);
date(3:5).datestring()
```

Comment: Thanks! One question though: How would I implement a lookup for another date in the vector? RIght now I'm using find(dates == myDate) to find the index of a given datestr, but how would that work in your implementation?

Comment: @phi: the double class implements `eq`, so the call should work the same as before. In case it does not (can't test right now) you could use `find(double(dates)==myDate)`

Comment: Yes, that works. However, its also the functionality i want to encapsulate :D My lookups are pretty complex, but often repeated, such as 'find date one year ago, which has to be a first wed of the month, if not exist, use thursday instead, but only if data ahs been announced, otherwise tuesday' and so on. I'd really like to get rid of that...

Comment: @phi: The class would support the find syntax as above, but for more complex lookups, you could have a method like `dates.find('reference',dates(12),'offset',-[1 0 0],'dayHierarchy',{'Wed','Thu','Tue'})`. To facilitate this, you may want to have a bunch of dependent properties (e.g. dayOfWeek, datevec, datestr), whose results you can cache to speed up calculations.

Comment: @phi: [example of lazy dependent property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961331/matlab-lazy-evaluation-in-dependent-property/4961387#4961387)